# Magento - Put barcode items in email order

Tags: magento-1.9, sku

I wish put near SKU also a barcode for any items that my customer order in the email with order.

is it possible?
thaks

Comment: yes it is possible, have you already generated the barcode or do you need to create the barcode too?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to use a service provider for this. Since the email is html you can add an image in the normal way and use a website like *barcodes4.me* to add the barcode itself.

```
<img src="http://www.barcodes4.me/barcode/i2of5/[numeric value].jpg" />
```

Read more about it here: http://www.barcodes4.me/apidocumentation

For more advanced barcodes you will need to prerender the image in some way. That would probably require some custom font that is converted to an image